# How to addComboBox Items dynamically in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF ,

I am adding items dynamically to a combobox like below

```
   objComboBox.Items.Add("<--Select-->");
```

Now i need to set value & index for the particular item . In asp.net i was doing

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("<--Select-->").Value ="-1"
```

I ma not finding appropriate method in wpf  . how can iI do this?

Answer (score 19):

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding cbItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedcbItem}"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> cbItems { get; set; }
public ComboBoxItem SelectedcbItem { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    cbItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();
    var cbItem = new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<--Select-->" };
    SelectedcbItem = cbItem;
    cbItems.Add(cbItem);
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Option 1" });
    cbItems.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Option 2"});
}
```

Comment: I'm curious.  cbItem is added to SelectedcbItem before it is added to cbItems.  Are there any problems or side-effects when the binding mechanism sees SelectedcdItem changed to an object that isn't yet on the bound collection?

Answer (score 4):

**Always try** to avoid accessing the UI directly. Use a `binding` to bind **data** to your control and `add`, `search`, `remove` whatever... **only on data**. To change a UI will take care of WPF binding itself.

An example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataBindingWithComboBoxes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
  combo.SelectedIndex = combo.Items.IndexOf("<--Select-->");
```

But better way is to use Binding as mentioned by snurre

Answer (score 0):

If it's first in the list you should use:
objComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
or
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;

If it's not the first then use:
objComboBox.SelectedItem = "<--Select-->";
or
DropDownList1.SelectedItem = "<--Select-->";